# Stop msgbox OK closing text input

Tags: vba, msgbox

Stressed out manager trying to fix a problem in our organisational CRM.

We have a macro set up to send 'ad hoc' text messages to clients. The character limit for the text input is 160, and if you exceed that, a msgbox pops up to tell you to reduce your text by x characters.

When you hit OK, it then kills the entire input box (so you have to re-type a new shorter version of your original message).

How can I set it up so that if you exceed the character limit, it tells you and then gives you the opportunity to go back and delete a few characters?

This is the portion of code I think is relevant:

```
set msgEntryDlg = CreateDialog("Adhoc SMS")
set msgTxtCtl = msgEntryDlg.AddControl("SMS Message: ",2, "")

if NOT msgEntryDlg.Execute then
  Msgbox "Message cancelled!"
  Exit sub
end if

mail_message = msgTxtCtl.Text
mail_message = " " + mail_message

If Len(mail_message) < 1 Then
  MsgBox "Message was empty, please enter a message!"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Len(mail_message) > 160 Then
  MsgBox "Message is too long, please reduce by " & (len(mail_message) - 160) & " characters.",4112
  Exit Sub
End If
```

I think it's something to do with a loop ... but I am clueless!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
Dim success As Boolean
Do
    Set msgEntryDlg = CreateDialog("Adhoc SMS")
    Set msgTxtCtl = msgEntryDlg.AddControl("SMS Message: ", 2, "")

    If Not msgEntryDlg.Execute Then
      MsgBox "Message cancelled!"
      Exit Do
    End If

    mail_message = msgTxtCtl.Text
    mail_message = " " + mail_message

    If Len(mail_message) < 1 Then
      MsgBox "Message was empty, please enter a message!"
    End If

    If Len(mail_message) > 160 Then
      MsgBox "Message is too long, please reduce by " & (Len(mail_message) - 160) & " characters.", 4112
    End If
    success = True
Loop Until success
```

If you need to repeat an action until a condition is met, check for the condition at the end of each loop.  Note that the cancellation exits the `Do`, not the `Sub`.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I just inserted that (replacing the entirety of the code I posted) and am now receiving an error message when trying to execute it: "Expected end of statement in sub/function <Main> ...' (the rest is sort of cut off, but it mentions line 42 which is the start of the new code). Any ideas?

Comment: @Kristina I'd need to see the rest of the code to integrate the loop.